# How to execute a DTSX package from windows 2000 server

Tags: sql, windows, ssis, dts

I am trying to execute a DTS package using DTSEXEC command from windows 2000 server.

I end up getting the error " DTSEXEC is not recognized as internal or external command"

Is there any way to achieve this task?

Comment: SSIS 2008 requires SQL Server 2008 Standard to be installed for the SSIS components (you do not have to install the database server).  However, SQL Server 2008 will not run on Windows 2000 Server.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.100).aspx#SE32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DTEXEC.EXE` is for SSIS (SQL Server > 2000). Instead, try `DTSRUN.exe` for DTS (SQL Server 2000).

Comment: Package was created in sql 2008 with extension .dtsx

Comment: Then you're not going to be able run it on a SQL Server 2000 DTS instance.

Comment: Is it possible to execute a dts package from a c# exe on 2000 machine?